# Why are sea dwelling mammals less aggressive than land dwelling mammals?

Tags: zoology

Many mammals on land seem to be quite dangerous to humans: e.g., tigers, lions, elephants, hypos etc. However, their sea-dwelling counterparts (e.g., orcas, dolphins, sea lions, whales etc.) are relatively friendly to humans (and in contrast to say sharks). Is there a simple reason for this?

Comment: Is there an objective way to measure friendliness of wild animals?

Comment: There is only one sea mammal specialized in eating seal sized prey and mammals, orcas. Why only one? that's tough, it's the solution to your query. Land based mammals prey substantially on large mammals, bears, big cats, wolves... When mammals size up another animal they think: "what is that animal shape doing? is it a food or a monster?" and "what is that face?" when they look at other animals. When sea mammals sea us they think "that's an alien from another world, he swims like a clown but his face is cool"

Answer (score 5):

**More encounters on land**

There are more land animals that meet humans walking around than there are sea animals that meet humans swimming around. If fewer attacks happen on humans in the sea environment, it might just be because there are fewer encounters with marine mammals than with land mammals.

**Greater species diversity on land**

In your list used as example, you cherry-picked a few aggressive(-ish) land mammals but the vast majority of land mammals are not aggressive toward humans. The fact that there are no marine mammal that are aggressive toward humans might just be because there are too few fewer marine mammal species.

**Pseudoreplication and phylogenetic signal**

I would argue that your sample size is not as large as you might think. There are only four lineages of mammals that evolve to live in the seas. There is therefore a phylogenetic signal and ignoring it would be a problem of pseudo replication.

For example, I could very well think of [territorial behaviour](https://www.britannica.com/science/territorial-behaviour) (which is where a lot of aggressive behaviour comes from) as having a strong phylogenetic signal.

**Why considering only humans?**

Your post title talks about aggressiveness in general and the content of your post talks about attacks against humans. It sounds that considering only attacks against humans to be very unfair. Orcas, typically, are fierce and violent predators although no orcas have ever attacked a human in the wild.

**Are they really that friendly to humans?**

There has been a number of attacks in captivity (well known cases with orcas). Also, there have been a number of whales attacks against boats (according to [this BBC article](https://www.canadiangeographic.ca/article/how-often-do-whales-attack-ships)).

**In short...**

In short, I think your comparison is unfair. I think you are looking for an explanation for a pattern that does not really exist.

Comment: I think there are actually 4 lineages of marine mammals: cetaceans (whales & dolphins), pinnipeds (seals & walruses), sirenia (manatees and dugongs), and mustelids (sea otters).  Maybe 5, if you include polar bears - which aren't all that friendly to humans.  Wikipedia has a diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_mammal

Comment: @jamesqf Thanks for correcting! I forgot sirenia and the sea otters. I edited the post

Comment: Another example of a predatory cetacean would be the sperm whale.  But since they prey mostly on squid that live at depths of 300-800 m or more, you are not in much danger from them.  Unless you are Captain Ahab, of course - and that was pure self-defense on Moby Dick's part :-)  (Yes, I know that's fiction, but it was inspired by actual events, notably the sinking of the Essex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essex_(whaleship) )

Answer (score 1):

They actually aren't less aggressive than terrestrial mammals. I've heard a lot of biologists talk about this weird trend in marine mammals (and more or less *only* marine mammals) where for some strange reason, marine mammals have this weird predilection for sexually assaulting other species. Warning, most of the below links are scientific articles or news sources reporting scientific articles, but they can still be a bit explicit due to the subject matter.

- [Bottlenose dolphins are well known for having sex with just about everything that moves](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1068/a38424?casa_token=ajSDeKZ3cOMAAAAA:mdqXAObwgMwDSTyMi3-5P6ryeX7xQBNBMbErWMzOrgS0GE_Ea6vbtTuI--xOjxleFRCP2g0Geho5qw), including other dolphins (of both genders), humans (there is actually a wealth of literature on this), *their own parents*, and other sea life, including the females and babies of other dolphin species (and the babies of their own, by the by). Gender, [willingness](https://www.proquest.com/docview/304999613?pq-origsite=gscholar&fromopenview=true), or even the fact of the other individual being *alive* need not matter. They've been known to drown baby porpoises due to assaulting them so hard, and then continue to have sex with the body. This isn't unique to bottlenoses but has also been documented to some degree in botos (*Inia geoffrensis*), dusky dolphins (*Lagenorhynchus obscurus*), and Hector's dolphins (*Cephalorhynchus hectori*). It hasn't been documented yet in orcas, though this is probably a tracking issue more than anything else.
- There's actually some evidence that dolphins may not be attacking other marine life for any definable survival or directly Darwinian reason, [but are doing it for *fun*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1689180/pdf/9699310.pdf) (or, from an etho-evolutionary perspective, the play behavior of killing or assaulting other marine life gives dolphins practice for when they commit infanticide on their own kind). [Dolphins, at the very least, are some of the few animals aside from great apes that are known to perform non-copulatory reproductive behavior for pleasure](https://www.newsweek.com/female-dolphins-appear-have-sex-pleasure-and-orgasms-thanks-their-well-1386150).
- [Sea otters are well known for sexually assaulting and raping female sea otters, and frequently they will do this to baby seals as well. They are so rough about it the females and baby seals often drown, and again like the bottlenoses the otters continue copulating with the body](https://www.iflscience.com/plants-and-animals/otters-are-not-cute-they-are-sick-depraved-jerks/)
- True seals aren't perpetual victims of this, as [grey seals have been observed sexually assaulting seals of other species](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-69986-w)
- [Elephant seals also get in on the act](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3812642), though so far only with their own species.
- Fur seals (a relative of sea lions, rather than true seals) [have been observed chasing down and forcibly copulating with penguins.](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/strange-but-true-seals-found-sexually-assaulting-penguins/) They sometimes eat them afterwards.

This is seemingly commonplace among marine mammals, and nobody really knows why. Some of it definitely seems to be purposeful rather than the result of misplaced instincts, at least the way the researchers in the primary literature listed in the articles linked describe it. However, you almost *never* hear about this among terrestrial mammals. The only thing I've heard close to this is how traumatized young bull African elephants have been known to kill adult rhinoceroses and try to copulate with the dead body, and in *that* case it's clearly not normal behavior for the species.

**So in at least some ways marine mammals are violent in ways that terrestrial mammals rarely are, and at least some of this (in the case of dolphins) is directed at humans.**